# How to read 'numbering library' field from Word document using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I'm using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing on ASP.NET Core project.
I want read tables data on document.
But when I'm trying read field created on 'numbering library', I get empty string value.
But on document that field contain for example "1.1.001".

```
using (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument doc = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument.Open(data.PathFile, true))
{
    var mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
    var tables = mainPart!.Document.Body!.Descendants<Table>();
    foreach (var table in tables)
    {
        var rows = table.Elements<TableRow>().ToList();
        if (rows.Count == 1) continue;
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            var cells = row.Elements<TableCell>().ToList();
        foreach(var cell in cells)
        {
                var testData = cell.InnerText; //string.Empty
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might well be that  the number isn't a child of TableCell at all. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee922775(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN